# find number greater than and less than

Tags: python, pandas

Thanks for your support in advance.

I read an excel file using panda `df = pd.read_excel(file)`, only one column
and i am looking for numbers bigger than 100 and less than 200 (`df>100 and df< 200`).

how can i do it?

`list_range=[105,101,150,160]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter the DataFrame using boolean indexing to select only the rows > 100 and  < 200.

```
filtered_df = df[(df['your_column_name'] > 100) & (df['your_column_name'] < 200)]
```